# Where date for specific condition only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Ok so what I want to do is use start and end date for one condition/specific rows/rows with this particular id only.

For example if **order_status='1'** ONLY then use start and end date and if **order_status='2'** then select ALL. I am using PHP to get this info from my database and then storing them in an array.

Currently, I have two different queries that accomplish this for me but I have to currently store them in two different arrays and display them as two different arrays as well. What I would like is a way to store all of this into one array and then use a foreach loop to echo all the results for both conditions in one place.

Hope it's clear enough but if not, please let me know by commenting and I'll include my code and query as well.

**Query for exporting with date (order_status=1)**

```
   SELECT ov.order_number,
   m.name           AS brand,
   op.name          AS model,
   op.product_grade AS grade,
   o.date_added
   FROM   `order` o,
   op.order_product_veri,
   manufacturer m,
   product p
   WHERE  opv.product_id = p.product_id
   AND p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
   AND op.order_status = '1'
   AND Date (o.date_added) >= '2013-10-22'
   AND Date(o.date_added) <= '2013-11-02'
```

**Query for exporting *without* date (order_status=2)**

```
   SELECT op.order_number,
   m.name           AS brand,
   op.name          AS model,
   op.product_grade AS grade,
   o.date_added
   FROM   `order` o,
   op.order_product_veri,
   manufacturer m,
   product p
   WHERE  opv.product_id = p.product_id
   AND p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
   AND op.order_status = '2'
```

Comment: You should include your code.

Comment: also your MySQL tables and redefine your question it isn't clear at all...

Comment: And learn to format SQL code AND use the ANSI JOIN syntax.. your second query abusing an bad syntax it's really easy to mis that you are using an INNER JOIN... SQL is meant to be readed not writed, SQL oneliners are bad for debugging or understanding the query..

Comment: @RaymondNijland properly formatted now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    op.order_number, 
    m.name AS brand, 
    op.name AS model, 
    op.product_grade AS grade, 
    o.date_added 
FROM 
    order o, 
    op.order_product_veri, 
    manufacturer m, 
    product p 
WHERE 
    opv.product_id = p.product_id and 
    p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id and
    (
        op.order_status = '2' or 
        (op_order_status = '1' and date(o.date_added) >= '2013-10-22' and date(o.date_added) <= '2013-11-02'
    )
```